# Applying fnFilter for multiple tables at once using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

For the following condition which applies dataTable function to all the tables with class name "sort"

```
var adminTables = $('.sort').dataTable()
```

How do I apply **fnFilter('some string')** function to all the tables selected in that particular page at once? I want to search multiple datatables at once.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using [fnFilterAll](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFilterAll) instead and experimented with it?

Here's a sample in jsbin (forked from the datatables site).

http://live.datatables.net/ukijec/edit#preview